# Keep getting TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found when using .join

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame of lists of names from different studios within a firm. I am trying to create a new column of names for each row with only the people from other studios. Some kind people helped me to write the code of how to put them together but now it's giving me this error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-0ad6b7d93f69> in <module>
     19     other_employees = deepcopy(studio_dev_emp_year)[row["year"], row["dev_parent"]]
     20     other_employees.remove(row["studio_dev_emp_year"])
---> 21     df.loc[i, "other_studio_emp"] = ",".join(other_employees)
     22 
     23 df.to_csv('studio_level.csv',mode='a',index=False, encoding="utf-8")

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found
```

After some search, it seems the error is because there are NaN values in the column. I tried to mitigate that by using some codes that I found but it keeps giving me the same message...
Below is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
from copy import deepcopy

filepath = "C:/Users/Untitled Folder/studio_level_dev.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(filepath,encoding='utf-8')
studio_dev_emp_year = {
    (year, dev_parent): list(
        df.loc[
            (df["year"] == year) & (df["dev_parent"] == dev_parent), "studio_dev_emp_year"
        ].values
    )
    for year in df["year"].unique()
    for dev_parent in df["dev_parent"].unique()
}
studio_dev_emp_year = {key: value for key, value in studio_dev_emp_year.items() if value}

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    other_employees = deepcopy(studio_dev_emp_year)[row["year"], row["dev_parent"]]
    other_employees.remove(row["studio_dev_emp_year"])
    df[i]= df.loc[df[i].notna(), "other_studio_emp"] = ",".join(other_employees)
    
df.to_csv('studio_level.csv',mode='a',index=False, encoding="utf-8")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to convert the `other_employees` items to strings first:

```py
other_employees = ['' for e in other_employees if np.isnan(e) else str(e)]
df[i] = df.loc[df[i].notna(), "other_studio_emp"] = ",".join(other_employees)
```

Comment: Hi now it has an error saying 'AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'astype''

Comment: Try this instead: `",".join([str(item) for item in other_employees])`

Comment: Thank you so much! @user17242583 now it runs and Python made a new column. But the only issue is that they substituted NaN to 'nan' string value, so 'nan' appears in the list of names. Do you think there's other way to do this?

Comment: What would you rather it be?

Comment: It would be better if it's an empty space or just removed. Right now it looks like "nan,Andy Finkel,Eric Cotton,,Andy Finkel,Eric Cotton,,Mike Horowitz,Shigeichi Ishimura"

Comment: Try adding this before the `",".join(...)` line:

Comment: `other_employees = ['' for e in other_employees if np.isnan(e) else e]`

Comment: It says " other_employees = ['' for e in other_employees if np.isnan(e) else e]
                                                                                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax " it seems there's something wrong with if else?

Comment: Yeah, I tried the updated answer it keeps saying there's a syntax error in the new line....